# Explanation on an example from the Circuitikz manual

Tags: circuitikz

I continue my learning of Circuitikz, trying to tackle a little more complex circuits.
I try to reproduce the diagram which appears in 3.3 (page 32) which includes an AO and two transistors.
After copying and pasting the code given in the manual, I have some comprehension questions and errors:

- lines 11 (`\draw (bb) --++(1,0) node[npn, anchor=B](Q1){} \bjtname{Q1};`) and 12 `\draw (bb1) --++(1,0) node[npn, anchor=B](Q2){} \bjtname{Q2};`lead me to "+ or - expected" and "give up on this path" errors : do I have to upload a specific package?
- what are the first two lines for ? `\def\killdepth#1{{\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{#1}}}` and `\newcommand\bjtname[1]{($(#1.C)!0.5!(#1.E)$) node[anchor=west]{\killdepth{#1}} }`

Thanks for your help.

I reproduce the code of the manual

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[european, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\def\killdepth#1{{\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{#1}}}
\newcommand\bjtname[1]{($(#1.C)!0.5!(#1.E)$) node[anchor=west]{\killdepth{#1}} }
\begin{circuitikz}[american, cute inductors]
\node [op amp](A1){\texttt{OA1}};
\draw (A1.-) to[short] ++(0,1) coordinate(tmp) to[R, l_=$R$] (tmp -| A1.out) to[short] (A1.out);
\draw (tmp) to[short] ++(0,1) coordinate(tmp) to[C=$C$] (tmp -| A1.out) to[short] (A1.out);
\draw (A1.+) to [battery2, invert] ++(0,-2.5) node[ground](GND){};
\draw (A1.-) to [L=$L$] ++(-2,0) coordinate(tmp) to[sV, l=$v_s$, fill=yellow] (tmp |-GND) node[ground]{};    
\draw (A1.out) to[R=$R_s$] ++(2,0) coordinate(bb) to[I, l_=$I_B$, invert] ++(0,2) node[vcc](VCC){};
\draw (bb) to[D, l=$D$, *-] ++(0,-2) coordinate(bb1) to[R=$R_m$] ++(0,-2) node[vee](VEE){};
\draw (bb) --++(1,0) node[npn, anchor=B](Q1){} \bjtname{Q1};
\draw (bb1) --++(1,0) node[pnp, anchor=B](Q2){} \bjtname{Q2};
\draw (Q1.E) -- (Q2.E) ($(Q1.E)!0.5!(Q2.E)$) to [short, *-o, name=S] ++(2.5,0) node[right]{$v_{o_Q}$};
\draw (S.s) to[european resistor, l=$Z_L$, *-] (S.s|-GND) node[ground]{};
\draw (Q1.C) -- (Q1.C|-VCC) node[vcc]{\SI{5}{V}};17\draw (Q2.C) -- (Q2.C|-VEE) node[vee]{\SI{-5}{V}};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas, please take a minute to adjust your snippet: there is a broken `\documentclass` line, a (clearly not related) `comment`-ed block, a missing `\end{document}` --- that way you make answering much more difficult for anyone. Thanks!

Comment: I'm so sorry: I had a really hard time making a single block of code. In the various hacks I've done, some parts must have been skipped.

Comment: Well, you can always edit your question --- that's the way of this site. Having nice questions and useful answers that will help other people in the future; this is why it is different from a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, once fixed the snippet so that it compiles, I can at least answer the questions:

1. I have no errors in your circuit; notice that the `+ or - expected` is often caused by forgetting the closing `$` in a calculated coordinate like `($(a)!0.5!(b)$)` (which finds the midpoint between the two coordinates, see Ti*k*Z manual 13.5 "coordinates calculations", around page 145).
2. `\bjtname` is a macro that I used to use to typeset transistor names before I fixed the automatic label positioning in version 0.9.7; you can see more comments in the `circuitikz` manual, section 3.17.4, around page 77:

   [image]

   I should change the tutorial; now writing just `node[npn](Q){Q}` should work ok. Thanks for the head-up, I'll take care of it as soon as I can. If you are not acquainted with macros, you can look at [this fine explanation.](https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-06) (scroll down to "defining commands").
3. `\killdepth` is another macro; I used plain TeX syntax here, another thing I should change in the manual. It is explained in the manual, I'll copy this here because I do not think I can explain it any better (no copyright problem, I wrote it!)...

   [image]
   [image]

   (page 17-18 --- you can just forget about it 99% of the times, but well, TeX/LaTeX is mostly about being finicky with the typesetting...).

Comment: As always, the answer is complete.
For the error found, I relaunched my code instantly and without having touched anything, it works: I hope it will continue like this.
For macros, I sometimes use them (I'm only at the beginning!): For the moment I'm trying to make clean circuits. The dressing with the texts will come in a second time: I will focus more on it at this time.
Thank you

Comment: @Nicolas https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers